# What is the difference between navigationBarTitle and navigationTitle in SwiftUI 2.0?

Tags: swiftui

I don't understand the exact difference between navigationBarTitle() and navigationTitle(). Can someone please explain when to use which?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `navigationTitle` is just SwiftUI 2.0 replacement for deprecated SwiftUI 1.0 `navigationBarTitle`

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, renamed: "navigationTitle(_:)")
@available(macOS, unavailable)
@available(tvOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, renamed: "navigationTitle(_:)")
@available(watchOS, introduced: 6.0, deprecated: 100000.0, renamed: "navigationTitle(_:)")
public func navigationBarTitle(_ title: Text) -> some View
```